# Is the Usage of Pursuit in this Context Right?

Tags: word-usage

Is the Usage of Pursuit in this Context Right:

> I've done everything I could in pursuit of her.

What I mean is I've tried everything I could to find her on the internet.

Comment: The use of the noun is grammatical, but _pursuit_ might be interpreted as a less than welcome search for the person. I encourage you to read in an _English language dictionary_, the meanings of the verb _to pursue._ Note that this does _not_ mean using Google "translate" to render the verb in English from your native language.

Comment: " pursuit might be interpreted as a less than welcome search for the person. " Could you elaborate?

Comment: I checked a dictionary and this came up: "the act of following or searching for someone or something, in order to catch or attack the person or thing:" and the example sentence was this: "The two children ran through the field in pursuit of their puppy." which seems like mine

Comment: So: do you want to "catch" or "attack" this person?

Comment: Never mind, I get it now. What if i were to say this: "I've done everything I could in pursuit of finding her but it was all in vain." is it right?

Comment: and I mean to catch that person

Comment: That is a _far_ preferable use of the noun _pursuit_. Excellent! Well understood. However, _catch_ implies that the object of pursuit does _not want to be caught._ It means that the pursuit is unwelcome. I encourage you to read an English language dictionary to understand the meaning of the verb "to catch".

Comment: I get it now so if I say I've searched all over town in pursuit of my daughter that would imply that she left the house and doesn't wanna be found or want to come back again could be because of abuse or privacy invasion or so right?

Comment: If an **adult** person does not wish to be "caught" in "Western" cultures, that does imply that any such _pursuit_ is unwelcome. However, it is important to note that cultural norms differ from country to country. Our goal here is only that you understand the current meanings of English words and phrases.

Answer (score -1):

Not really.

> **pursuit**

means to *chase*, but usually on the internet you **search for** or **lookup** someone.  So I assume you were not ***chasing*** her on the internet.

Usually the only kind of **pursuit** on the internet would be to chase after a rogue *process* (malware) or *person*  (hacker) as they start taking over servers.

Comment: I get it now so if I say I've searched all over town in pursuit of my daughter that would imply that she left the house and doesn't wanna be found or want to come back again could be because of abuse or privacy invasion or so right?